# Query records in batch to select records created as today and after 5PM yesterday

Tags: batch

How can I add condition in a start query to query records which are being created today and yesterday after 5PM.
As we have a scheduled batch at 5PM every day.

Comment: welcome to SFSE; please see [ask] for getting the most from the Community

Answer (score 2):

Try this,
Date d = Date.Today().addDays(-1);
DateTime dt = DateTime.newInstance(d.year(), d.month(), d.day(), 17, 0, 0);
system.debug('Required DateTime : '+dt);
system.debug('Query : '+[SELECT Name, CreatedDate FROM Account WHERE CreatedDate > :dt]);